# Assign value to variable

Tags: c#, interface

I have this variable, it's an instance of a Interface of a class in business layer.
I need to send messages since data access layer, to business layer and finally to presentation layer. I my class "LogBinaryWriter" in data access I have this:

```
public class LogBinaryWriter : ILogBinaryWriter
{
   private readonly IImageLogBuilder _imageLogBuilder;

   public void WriteFrameCodes(string filePath, int logSelected)
   {
     var fileExists = FileExists(binaryFilePath);
     if (fileExists == true)
     {
        _imageLogBuilder.displayMessage("The file " + binaryFileName + " exist.             Dou you want overwrite it? (Y/N)");
     }
   }
}
```

I have a message: "the value **_imageLogBuilder** is never assigned and will always be null"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you actually READ the message? It answers your question.

Comment: You are getting the error because you need to create a new object and assign it to _imageLogBuilder. You can't create an instance of an interface, there has to be a class that implements that interface (for example `public class MyImageLogBuidler : IImageLogBuilder { ... }`). Then you assign a new instance of that class to your variable. Please see the updates to my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Instantiate an instance of `IImageLogBuilder` in your constructor for `LogBinaryWriter` and assign it to `_imageLogBuilder`. You would have to do it in the constructor since you have `_imageLogBuilder` marked as `readonly`.

For example, assuming you have a class called `MyImageLogBuilder` that implements `IImageLogBuilder`:

```
public LogBinaryWriter()
{
    _imageLogBuilder = new MyImageLogBuilder();
}
```

You could also overload the constructor so you can pass in the `IImageLogBuilder` you want to use (lookup constructor injection for more info on this pattern):

```
public LogBinaryWriter(IImageLogBuilder imageLogBuilder)
{
    _imageLogBuilder = imageLogBuilder;
}
```

Remember, you will need a class that implements the `IImageLogBuilder` interface to be able to create a new instance and assign it to the `_imageLogBuilder` variable. For example:

```
public interface IImageLogBuilder
{
    void Log(string message);
}

//The class below IMPLEMENTS the IImageLogBuilder interface
public class MyImageLogBuilder : IImageLogBuilder
{
   //Implement IImageLogBuilder methods here
   public void Log(string message)
   {
      //Log message
   }
}
```

If you had something like the classes defined above then you could the following in the `LogBinaryWriter` constructor and you would no longer get the null reference error.

```
public LogBinaryWriter()
{
    _imageLogBuilder = new MyImageLogBuilder();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an instance of a class that implements `IImageLogBuilder` interface to `_imageLogBuilder` field.

Right now your field will always have a value of `null`.

For example:

```
private readonly IImageLogBuilder _imageLogBuilder = new ImageLogBuilder();
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps initialize `_imageLogBuilder` in constructor ?

```
public class LogBinaryWriter : ILogBinaryWriter
{
   private readonly IImageLogBuilder _imageLogBuilder;

   public LogBinaryWriter(IImageLogBuilder imageLogBuilder)
   {
      _imageLogBuilder = imageLogBuilder;
   }
....


}
```

Comment: I can't make a constructor, because I'm  using the default constructor of LogBinaryWriter in other clasess. Another way please??

Comment: can you remove the `readonly` attribute and introduce a setter?

Comment: something like this??  private IImageLogBuilder _imageLogBuilder { get; private set; } ...

Answer (score 1):

You never set the value of the `_imageLogBuilder` variable. And since you marked it as `readonly`, the only place it can be set is in a field initializer, or in a constructor.

Did you mean to do something like this, perhaps?

```
private readonly IImageLogBuilder _imageLogBuilder = // get the value from somewhere else, or make a new one
```